# Get total disc from arraylist sqlite android

Tags: loops, android-sqlite

I have a table data like this
[tbl images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ol0n.png)

how to calculate POD_PRDCD
which has the value POD_DISC1 and POD_DISC2 to get the value POH_DISC2 use looping from tbl_detail.

i have tried like this

```
private double BOHDISC2() { 
Double DISC2 = 0.0; 
Double TDISC1 = 0.0;

ArrayList<POModels> data = dbController.getAllDBPO(); 
for(int i = 0 ; i < data.size(); i++) { 

if (data.get(i).getPoddisc2() != null) { 
DISC2 += (Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getPrice()) * Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getQty())) -
                       (Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getPrice()) * Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getQty()) * Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getPoddisc1())/100) ; 
Log.e("DISC 2", String.valueOf(DISC2));

TDISC1 += (DISC2) * Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getPoddisc2())/100; 
Log.e("TDISC 2", String.valueOf(TDISC1));

pohdisc2.setText(String.valueOf(TDISC1));

           }
        } return TDISC1;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to calculate the sum of POD_DISC1 + POD_DISC2 per NOPO then you can do this simply with SQLite e.g.

```
SELECT sum(pod_disc1 + pod_disc2) AS pod_prodcd FROM tbl_detail GROUP BY pod_nopo;
```

- a `WHERE` clause could be used to limit the result e.g. for a single nopo then `WHERE pod_nopo = 'po-0104-2023-02-00119'` *(no need for the GROUP BY as there is then just the single group)*
- of course the subquery could be used within a query say to update the tbl_header

**Demo**

Here's a demo that will get the sum per nopo and then incoporate the query into an update that changes the poh_qtypo column to be that value (just as an example):-

```
/* Cleanup the demo environment in case it is dirty */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_detail;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_header;
/* Create and populate the demo environment */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_header (poh_nopo TEXT PRIMARY KEY, poh_qtypo REAL, poh_gross REAL, poh_disc1 REAL,poh_disc2 REAL);
INSERT INTO tbl_header VALUES('po-0104-2023-02-00119',15.00,20000,4000,485);
INSERT INTO tbl_header VALUES('po-9999-2023-02-00119',21.00,50000,9000,999);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_detail (pod_nopo TEXT,pod_prodcd REAL,pod_qtypo REAL, pod_hrgbeli REAL,pod_disc1 REAL, pod_disc2 REAL);
INSERT INTO tbl_detail VALUES
    ('po-0104-2023-02-00119',103115,5.00,20000.00,0.00,0.00),
    ('po-0104-2023-02-00119',4911021,5.00,10000.00,5.00,0.00),
    ('po-0104-2023-02-00119',102894,5.00,10000.00,3.00,1.00)
;

/* Demo 1 get the sum of disc1 + disc 2 per nopo */
SELECT sum(pod_disc1 + pod_disc2) AS pod_prodcd FROM tbl_detail GROUP BY pod_nopo; /*<<<<< Result 1*/

/* Show the headers (before updating) */
SELECT * FROM tbl_header; /* Result 2 */

/* Example using the query above as a subquery in an update */
WITH 
    /* use a CTE (comon table expression to drive the update, so all nopo's can be updated) */
    pkey(k) AS (SELECT DISTINCT poh_nopo FROM tbl_header) /* get ALL poh_nopo's (but no duplicates, shouldn't be if poh_nopo is Primary key) */
    UPDATE tbl_header SET 
        poh_qtypo = coalesce(
            (
                /* The subquery */
                SELECT sum(pod_disc1 + pod_disc2) 
                FROM tbl_detail 
                WHERE pod_nopo=poh_nopo), /* adapted to only get the applicable nopo rows for the header row being updated */
                0.00 /* if no rows (e.g. the po0999-.... ) then instead of null use 0.00 */
            ) 
    WHERE poh_nopo IN (SELECT * FROM pkey)
;
/* show the headers (after the update) */
SELECT * FROM tbl_header; /* Result 3 */
/* Clean up the demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_detail;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_header;
```

**Results**

First the sum of disc + disc2 per nopo (result 1) :-

```
pod_prodcd
9.0
```

Next before the update of the header:-

```
poh_nopo                poh_qtypo   poh_gross   poh_disc1   poh_disc2
po-0104-2023-02-00119   15          20000       4000        485
po-9999-2023-02-00119   21          50000       9000        999
```

After the update of the header :-

```
poh_nopo                poh_qtypo   poh_gross   poh_disc1   poh_disc2
po-0104-2023-02-00119   9           20000       4000        485
po-9999-2023-02-00119   0           50000       9000        999
```

i.e. poh_qtypo  for 0104 is **9** (5.00 + 3.00 + 1.00) and for 9999 is **0** as there are no detail rows

**If what you want is that pod_prdcd is updated to reflect the sum then this can be done by using:-**

```
UPDATE tbl_detail SET pod_prodcd = round(pod_disc1 + pod_disc2,2);
```

e.g. :-

```
pod_nopo                pod_prodcd  pod_qtypo   pod_hrgbeli pod_disc1   pod_disc2
po-0104-2023-02-00119   0           5           20000            0          0
po-0104-2023-02-00119   5           5           10000            5          0
po-0104-2023-02-00119   4           5           10000            3          1
```

However there is no need to have the pod_prodcd column as the value can always be calculated on the fly e.g.

```
SELECT pod_nopo, round(pod_disc1 + pod_disc2,2) AS pod_prodcd, pod_qtypo, pod_hrgbeli, pod_disc1, pod_disc2 FROM tbl_detail;
```

which produces:-

```
po-0104-2023-02-00119   0.0 5   20000   0   0
po-0104-2023-02-00119   5.0 5   10000   5   0
po-0104-2023-02-00119   4.0 5   10000   3   1
```

- There is no wasteful updating, and
- There is less data stored and thus less storage space taken and therefore an improvement in efficiency, and also
- The data is normalised as the data isn't being duplicated as such.

You may wish to refer to:-

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html (CTE's aka **WITH**)
- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round (scalar functions)
- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html (Aggregate functions aka GROUP functions)

in short SQLite's **SQL** is quite powerful and can greatly reduce programming code.

**Android (Java) Example**

Assuming the intent is to get disc1 + disc per detail (and also to further demonstrate the % of disc1 and disc 2) then consider the following working Android demo.

First the DatabaseHelper (i.e. class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper) i.e. **DBHelper** :-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABSE_NAME = "the_database";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABSE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    private static volatile DBHelper  instance;
    static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            return new DBHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static final String TABLE_HEADER = "tbl_header";

    /* CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_header (poh_nopo TEXT PRIMARY KEY, poh_qtypo REAL, poh_gross REAL, poh_disc1 REAL,poh_disc2 REAL); */
    public static final String HEADER_COL_NOPO = "poh_nopo";
    public static final String HEADER_COL_QTYPO = "poh_qtypo";
    public static final String HEADER_COL_GROSS = "poh_gross";
    public static final String HEADER_COL_DISC1 = "poh_disc1";
    public static final String HEADER_COL_DISC2 = "poh_disc2";
    private static final String HEADER_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_HEADER + "(" +
            HEADER_COL_NOPO + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY" +
            "," + HEADER_COL_QTYPO + " REAL " +
            "," + HEADER_COL_GROSS + " REAL " +
            "," + HEADER_COL_DISC1 + " REAL " +
            "," + HEADER_COL_DISC2 + " REAL " +
            ");";

    /*CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_detail (pod_nopo TEXT,pod_prodcd REAL,pod_qtypo REAL, pod_hrgbeli REAL,pod_disc1 REAL, pod_disc2 REAL);*/
    public static final String TABLE_DETAIL = "tbl_detail";
    public static final String DETAIL_COL_NOPO = "pod_nopo";
    public static final String DETAIL_COl_PRODCD = "pod_prodcd";
    public static final String DETAIL_COl_QTYPO = "pod_qtypo";
    public static final String DETAIL_COL_HRGBELI = "pod_hrgbeli";
    public static final String DETAIL_COL_DISC1 = "pod_disc1";
    public static final String DETAIL_COL_DISC2 = "pod_disc2";
    private static final String DETAIL_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAIL + "(" +
            DETAIL_COL_NOPO + " TEXT " +
            "," + DETAIL_COl_PRODCD + " REAL " +
            "," + DETAIL_COl_QTYPO + " REAL" +
            "," + DETAIL_COL_HRGBELI + " REAL" +
            "," + DETAIL_COL_DISC1 + " REAL " +
            "," + DETAIL_COL_DISC2 + " REAL" +
            ");";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(HEADER_CRTSQL);
        db.execSQL(DETAIL_CRTSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertHeader(String nopo, double qtypo, double gross, double disc1, double disc2) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(HEADER_COL_NOPO,nopo);
        cv.put(HEADER_COL_QTYPO, qtypo);
        cv.put(HEADER_COL_GROSS, gross);
        cv.put(HEADER_COL_DISC1, disc1);
        cv.put(HEADER_COL_DISC2,disc2);
        return this.getReadableDatabase().insert(TABLE_HEADER,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertDetail(String nopo, double prodcd, double qtypo, double hrgbeli, double disc1, double disc2) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DETAIL_COL_NOPO,nopo);
        cv.put(DETAIL_COl_PRODCD,prodcd);
        cv.put(DETAIL_COl_QTYPO,qtypo);
        cv.put(DETAIL_COL_HRGBELI,hrgbeli);
        cv.put(DETAIL_COL_DISC1,disc1);
        cv.put(DETAIL_COL_DISC2,disc2);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_DETAIL,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllDetailsWithDisc1AddedToDisc2() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TABLE_DETAIL,new String[]{
                        DETAIL_COL_NOPO,
                        "round(" + DETAIL_COL_DISC1 +" + " + DETAIL_COL_DISC2 + ",2) AS " + DETAIL_COl_PRODCD,
                        DETAIL_COl_QTYPO,
                        DETAIL_COL_HRGBELI,
                        DETAIL_COL_DISC1,
                        DETAIL_COL_DISC2,
                        "coalesce((" + DETAIL_COL_DISC1 + " / (" + DETAIL_COL_DISC1 + "+" + DETAIL_COL_DISC2 + ") * 100),0) AS disc1_percent",
                        "coalesce((" + DETAIL_COL_DISC2 + " / (" + DETAIL_COL_DISC1 + "+" + DETAIL_COL_DISC2 + ") * 100),0) AS disc2_percent",
                },
                null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- as can be seen everything database wise is included in the helper. So it's just a matter of getting an instance (singleton) and then using the instance to insert and extract data.

As such some activity code that inserts data (along the lines of the data provided in the question (typos may exist)):-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = DBHelper.getInstance(this);
        db.insertHeader("po-0104-2023-02-00119",15.00,20000,4000,485);
        db.insertHeader("po-9999-2023-02-00119",21.00,50000,9000,999);
        db.insertDetail("po-0104-2023-02-00119",103115,5.00,20000.00,0.00,0.00);
        db.insertDetail("po-0104-2023-02-00119",4911021,5.00,10000.00,5.00,0.00);
        db.insertDetail("po-0104-2023-02-00119",102894,5.00,10000.00,3.00,1.00);

        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(db.getAllDetailsWithDisc1AddedToDisc2());
    }
}
```

When run the data is inserted and can be seen. via App Inspection, to be:-

[image]

and :-

[image]

The extract aka the Cursor, is for brevity, just dumped to the log and is:-

```
023-02-23 15:25:12.388 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@98fd0f5
2023-02-23 15:25:12.388 I/System.out: 0 {
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_nopo=po-0104-2023-02-00119
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_prodcd=0
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_qtypo=5
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_hrgbeli=20000
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_disc1=0
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_disc2=0
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    disc1_percent=0
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    disc2_percent=0
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out: }
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out: 1 {
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_nopo=po-0104-2023-02-00119
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_prodcd=5
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_qtypo=5
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_hrgbeli=10000
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_disc1=5
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_disc2=0
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    disc1_percent=100
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    disc2_percent=0
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out: }
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out: 2 {
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_nopo=po-0104-2023-02-00119
2023-02-23 15:25:12.389 I/System.out:    pod_prodcd=4
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out:    pod_qtypo=5
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out:    pod_hrgbeli=10000
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out:    pod_disc1=3
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out:    pod_disc2=1
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out:    disc1_percent=75
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out:    disc2_percent=25
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out: }
2023-02-23 15:25:12.390 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- as can be seen there is no need for the **prodcd** column assuming this is to be disc1 + disc2 as this value can be generated on the fly (derived from existing columns) (disc1 and disc2 are also used to determine the percent each uses, again derived values so no need to store them).